# Could the type of sql data type have an impact on the composition of a sql query?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have written some sql queries to generate data from a postgresql database. When I try to search for a word (for example work) It works but if I carry out the same for a bigint (for example 45), I got no result.  I got the following error: Warning: pg_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in require().
See fiddle for the database 
Could it have something to do with the fact it's a bigint? Has it to be defined differently.

```
$table = "test";
$field="\"number\"";
$text = "45"; # $text = 45;
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT \"number\", \"word\", \"sentence\", lower(\"sentence\") FROM \"" . $table . "\" WHERE ";
$query = $query . $field . " ~* '" . $text . "' ";
echo $query;

$recordset = pg_query($connection, $query);
if($recordset)
{
    $row = pg_numrows ($recordset);
    var_dump($row);
}
```

## Definition of table test:

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
  "id" SERIAL,
  "number" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "word" VARCHAR,
  "sentence" VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO test (id, number, word, sentence) VALUES
    (1, "451", 'make', 'I will make you great'),
    (2, "45", 'new', 'Is this new ?'),
    (3, "57", 'work', 'I always work very hard'),
    (4, "48", 'sell', 'Are you going to sell your house'),
    (5, "781", 'feel', 'Do you feel well?')
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add the SQL that is in `$query`? Please also add the definition of the table `test`. It is weird that you try to compare a field that has the suggestive name `number` with a query that expects the column `number` to have a stringy type. Also, your code has a typo - you set `$talbe` but you use `$table` in your query string.

Comment: What do you mean with adding the SQL that is the $query?

Comment: You have `echo $query;` in your code. What does it output? Please add that output to your pst.

Comment: It doesn't give anything as output. I just got the error.

Comment: I had once the same problem. So I changed the bigint to varchar. Use then $text = 45;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL fiddle where you say it works uses MySQL, so it is irrelevant here.

This does not work and causes an error, because PostgreSQL does not have implicit type casts from numeric to string data types and vice versa. The reason is that with function and operator overloading, this would create ambiguities and surprising behavior in certain cases.

The solution for you is to use a type cast:

```
... WHERE CAST(number AS text) ~* '^45.*'
```

Comment: No, that wouln't help. It is not the constant, it is the `number ~*` that causes the problem.

Comment: Then it cannot be PostgreSQL. What is the exact SQL string you are trying?

Comment: .CAST ($field AS text) . " ~* '" . $text . "'  => $text = "^".$text.".*";  => I got an error because he doesn't recognise the ^and * symbol. But I found a solution a just changed the bigint to varchar and then it worked.